# How to optimize google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

How to optimize google chrome?
I know that it is already fast, but do you know of some way that can make it even faster.

Comment: Have you heard the phrase "Premature Optimisation"?

Comment: Make Google Chrome even faster and you'll be able to travel backwards in time. Sounds like a cool feature to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would turn off error reporting if it isn't off already.

Also, under "Personal Stuff", tell Chrome not to Remember any passwords or form entries. This probably will only help marginally.

You can improve performance of any browser by cleaning history and cache regularly. Try CCleaner for that. (www.CCleaner.com)

Comment: Cleaning your cache too regularly will make it slower - the cache is there so the browser doesn't have to redownload stuff that doesn't change.

Comment: It depends - the browser has less to dig through. Have you ever tried loading Google Mail over a slow connection? Sometimes, it will suggest cleaning the cache. I guess the operative word in your comment is *too*. Good point +1

Comment: I would argue that using CCleaner too regularly is better than never using it, but of course the best way to do it is in moderation.

Answer (score -1):

if you value your privacy, you should run **[UnChrome](http://www.abelssoft.net/unchrome.php)**. It will anonymize Chrome by replacing your unique ID with Null values so that your browser can no longer be identified. The functionality is not affected by this. You only need to apply UnChrome once.

or even better: switch to **[SWare Iron](http://www.srware.net/en/software_srware_iron.php)** (based on the Chromium-source) which offers the same features as Chrome - **but without the critical points concerning privacy**.

Comment: Does this actuallty improve performance? Or are you just talking about privacy?